# Delphi exeption EOleSysError - класс не зарегистрирован

Tags: delphi

При трансляции программы на Delphi сообшение: exeption EOleSysError - класс не зарегистрирован? Как устранить

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте установить на систему [Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 2.8 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5793) и запустить программу на исполнение еще раз.

Вообще есть смысл пройтись трассировщиком до точки кода, выкидывающей исключение. Скорее всего, это будет какой-нибудь компонент ActiveX. Надо определить, не требует ли он каких-либо внешних зависимостей. Если да, установить их.

Плюс полезно обновить всю систему: Windows Update и тд.